# VLC playing vid over samba stuttering?

Tags: networking, samba, vlc, streaming

This is sort of an open ended question, so any recommendations will be appreciated

I have a ubuntu box as my main server and I stream video on my mac since I can't carry my server box upstairs

This is my current configuration: My mac connects to my linux box via samba and basically mounts the shared folder as a network drive. I am using VLC player to play videos over this network drive and I find that the quality of the video is not as optimal as I would like it to be - seeking takes a good 10 seconds while I get the occasional stuttering (green screen) playing 540p videos, let alone 1080p.

My current setup permits a 1.8 MB/s bandwidth (tested with SCP), so I don't think network latency is that big an issue here.

I have trouble tweaking VLC because I am not technically streaming videos in the VLC player - VLC has no idea I am playing over a LAN network. Hence, I am unable to set the stream buffer and cache values that are specific only to network streaming on VLC.

Is there anything I can do to improve my current set up? Will using a media streaming server help (like Amahi)? Are there more efficient protocols than SMB for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Webdav instead. It is a HTTP based file share. This is the direction I am currently leaning. I just started researching this as a option. I have a 8tb raid5 running ubuntu server and streaming to multiple VER1 Apple TV's stripped of factory OS and running XBMC. (trying to cut the cord with sat. provider) Having issues with samba and looking for an alternative. XBMC supports webdav natively so it seemed like a natural next thing to try. Other things you could look at is 
adding XMBC or PLEX software to handle it. Nice thing about that is the pretty interface you get for browsing you content

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

if you want a quick overview. There is also a wiki page for setup help.

Comment: I don't use VLC so not sure of what it will or won't do.